# Always use "memory" for variables created within functions. Bad practice?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage, memory

Is it bad practice to systematically use the `memory` keyword for variables declared within a function (other than constructor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to explicitly use `memory` or `storage` to clarify whether a variable contains a pointer to memory or storage.

You should not always use the `memory` keyword, because it could make your code really inefficient: When you're assigning an array from storage to a `memory` pointer variable, the entire array will be read from storage and copied into memory.

Here's an example of a situation where you should *not* use `memory`:

```
contract Test
{
    uint256[1000] lotsOfNumbersInStorage;
    uint256[1000] moreNumbersInStorage;
    function calculateSomething(uint256 a) public view returns(uint256)
    {
        uint256[1000] memory theChosenArray;
        if (a > 0) theChosenArray = lotsOfNumbersInStorage;
        else theChosenArray = moreNumbersInStorage;
        return theChosenArray[3] * theChosenArray[a];
    }
}
```

Those assignments to `theChosenArray` look innocent, but they will copy the entire array from storage into memory, which will cost at least 200000 gas (200 gas per storage read * 1000 elements). In this case, you should declare `theChosenArray` as a `storage` pointer, not a `memory` pointer.

Comment: Wrt your code snippet: the 2 arrays you initially declared are on storage by default, since they are arrays, isn't it?

Comment: @hartmut They are in storage because they have been declared inside the contract and not inside a function

Comment: Thx for this precision. Is any variable declared inside a contract, rather than inside a function, BY DEFAULT, in storage?

Comment: @hartmut Yes, that is correct